# Call controller from controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm kind of newbie, want my app to show next screen after some delay.
Basically i've created controller and added spinner to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    sleep(5);
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Next i want to show my next controller called `EntryViewController`. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Ill add any info if needed

Comment: Just a heads up. You should never use `sleep` in production code. There are much better methods (like Vin's below). `Sleep` can be used for testing delays but not for usable, reliable code.

Comment: its just a prototype. On real app there will be url request, so i will have to call controller after request done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-performSelector` method like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

In `-yourMethod` you can add code to navigate to next view controller :

```
-(void)yourMethod
{
    //Write the code for Navigation.
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Don't forget to take a look at [**NSObject Class Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: basically i need some example on how to navigate to next view controller

Comment: @Avdept Are you using storyboards, xibs, or solely code for your views/view controllers?

Comment: @Avdept : Don't you know about Google ? I gave you the Idea on which path you should go. You can search that part easily in Google, I guess. Just search on Google with what you wrote in your 1st Comment and you will easily get 100s of links on that.

Answer (score 1):

a. Don't use `sleep` in your main thread, as it blocks the whole GUI.

b. Don't do animation in `viewDidLoad`, as the view hasn't appeared yet at this stage. Instead use `viewDidAppear`.

c. There are different ways to "show" a view controller. Here's the code for presenting the view controller (ie the view controller won't be pushed on to a `UINavigationController`). Have a look at [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) for more info on presenting view controllers. The code also addresses points above

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [spinner startAnimating];

double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController: EntryViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

The use of `dispatch` is a bit advanced, but you should really learn it.